The Minimal Multiplicative Monster
Today I wondered what the formula for the smallest number divisible by all the positive integers $\le n$. I called it $M(n)$, where the M stands for all the Ms in Minimal Multiplicative Monster. I found this formula as I was thinking about eating some pie:
$$M(n) = \prod_{i=1}^{\pi(n)} p_i^{\lfloor \log_{p_i}(n) \rfloor}$$
Where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime number, and $\pi(n)$ is the number of primes $\le n$.
My hope of investigating this function further without help vanished as I saw what it was. I wouldn't know how to graph it with GeoGebra, nor do I have a clue what kind of interpolations exist, and what its difference function is, or what the derivatives of its most popular interpolations are.
Therefore, my questions is, what is this function called and where can I read about it?

This should be A003418.
